# How to remove margin to left of ul positioned with grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a very simple grid:

```
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

to style ten list items:

```
  <body>
    <ul id="grid">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>

    </ul>
  </body>
```

The above code outputs a grid that has a margin on the left side, how can I remove this (https://jsfiddle.net/0z9xuyc4/2/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<ul>` element has a default left padding of 40px ([Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)).

Add `padding-left: 0` style to your `#grid {}` selector and it will work as you want to.

In future you can use Web Inspector in the browser to see if it's a padding or margin.